# SQL query not returning expected values when summing total values in a column

Tags: python, sql, multiple-columns

I have this schema:

- `Students` (sid: int, firstName: str, lastName: str, yearStarted: int)
- `Majors` (sid: int, major: str)
  Note: a student may have more than one major.
- `Grades` (sid: int, cid: int, credits: int, grade: int)
  Note: sid, cid=foreign keys, grades: A=4, B=3, C=2, D=1, F=0.
- `Courses` (cid: int, number: int, professor: str, major: str, year: int, semester: str)
  Note: cid is unique across semesters. Semester is either Summer, Fall, or Spring. Two course offerings are the same if they have same number + major

And with this schema I need to "Provide the SQL query that will generate the first name, last name, yearStarted, and the total number of credits for every student. You should not consider courses with a 0 grade, since these correspond to failed courses"

So far I have this:

```
def q4(self):
    query = '''
    select s.firstName, s.lastName, s.yearStarted,count(*)
    from students s, grades g
    where s.sid = g.sid
    and g.grade >0
    group by s.firstName, s.lastName, s.yearStarted
    '''
    self.cur.execute(query)
    all_rows = self.cur.fetchall()
    return all_rows
```

and returns these values:

[('Anne', 'Brown', 2020, 1),
('Jack', 'Thomson', 2018, 3),
('Jacob', 'McKarthy', 2020, 2),
('Jamal', 'Jones', 2019, 3),
('Jane', 'Doe', 2017, 2),
('John', 'Doe', 2017, 3),
('Tim', 'Burton', 2018, 3),
('Tina', 'Gilligan', 2019, 3)]

But apparently these are wrong, and when I upload to gradescope it gives me these errors located in the attached image[image]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you are choosing *not* to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: seems to me you have all the students but you have a different order than, does the exercise specify and order of the students?

Comment: @GordonLinoff No, there is not. I HAVE used an inner join based on sid, and ended up with the sane errors.

Comment: @GordonLinoff this is obviously a student, maybe tone it down a bit?

Comment: "and the total number of credits for every student" 

may be you need sum(g.credits) instead of count(*)?

Comment: @ChristianSloper So looking at my errors, it should be grouped by s.yearStarted desc?

Comment: @terehpp I tried both ways, and the count(*) works fine.

Comment: @ChristianSloper got it! thank you so much for the hint, realized i just needed to group by id, yearStarted

Comment: No, it's not the `GROUP BY` that must be different, but the `ORDER BY`. It is strange though, they don't say which order they want in the description, but then tell you your result doesn't match, only because it is in another order than they expect.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes sorry thats what i meant and what I did. And it is weird for the result, but I posted the answer that passed the automatic grader!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the answer. Thank you to @ChristianSloper for helping me

```
def q4(self):
    query = '''
    select s.firstName, s.lastName, s.yearStarted,count(*)  as cnt
    from students s, grades g
    where s.sid = g.sid
    and g.grade >0
    group by s.sid, s.yearStarted
    order by s.yearStarted
    desc
     
    '''
    self.cur.execute(query)
    all_rows = self.cur.fetchall()
    return all_rows
```

Comment: Yep, it seems the only missing thing was the `ORDER BY`, which is not in the task description you have shown us, however. As firstname + lastname + yearstarted are probably unique in the table, you get the same result grouping by these or by the id (when grouping by the id, the yearstarted is superfluous in `GROUP BY`). You should not use comma-separated joins. They were used until explicit joins got invented - which was in 1992! If you are still taught these, this sheds a bad light on your class, book or tutorial. (One should know they exist, but we don't use them anymore.)

Comment: And be sure to always use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @Parfait Agreed, I know its not the best way to do it. Will be using explicit joins from here on out. Thank you all for the advice!